# Why, when we impose restrictions such as the ones of our physical world, new properties arise?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, soft-question, physics

Unfortunately I am not and expert mathematician nor a philosopher so I don't have the right words to phrase the concept, but the following example should be able to make the question clear:

Take the complex numbers. We can't impose an order relationship between them (>, <). But as we impose a new constrain by saying that $\sqrt{-1}$ doesn't exist, we find that we can now tell which number is bigger than another.

How can we rigorously explain what's going on?

EDIT: Second example concerning Achilles and the tortoise removed since multiple users pointed out that it contained numerous errors. Minor corrections.

Comment: I get what you mean, but your explanation for these phenomena isn't accurate. That being said, the answer to your titular question is quite simple: Given a stricter set of restrictions, there are less objects that satisfy those restrictions, and hence, more you can say about those objects in general.

Comment: Your point $(1)$ isn't entirely accurate. "Take Achilles and the tortoise. In a world where actual uncountable infinities do exists, we get this paradox." Uncountability has nothing to do with this - the only assumption it makes on the structure of space is *density* (which doesn't imply uncountability - think about $\mathbb{Q}$). In fact, we can *still* resolve the paradox even if space is dense, or even continuous, by thinking more carefully about limits.

Comment: More to the point, as Don Thousand says narrower classes of objects have more guaranteed properties a priori. You're focusing on **tameness** properties, but it's also worth noting that we can get guaranteed **pathologies** this way too. For example:

$(1)$ In passing from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, we lose algebraic closure - we can't find solutions to polynomial equations anymore in general.

$(2)$ In passing from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, we lose the ability to divide.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, even if I didn't have the right words and examples. Thanks!

Comment: For #1, it hasn't been shown that the spacetime is discrete at a quantum level. The resolution of the paradox certainly can't rely on something that may or may not be true in the first place. The Achilles and tortoise paradox is resolved *whether or not* the universe has a discrete structure.

Comment: You are completely wrong about the complex numbers. All modern physics is based on them.

Answer (score 5):

*Turning my comment above into an answer:*

As Don Thousand commented above, narrower classes of objects have more guaranteed properties a priori. You're focusing on tameness properties, but it's also worth noting that we can get guaranteed pathologies this way too. For example, here are a couple ways in which adding a natural requirement to a starting class of structures can limit our ability to do algebra:

- When we shift from the class of *all* fields (which includes both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$) to the class of *ordered* fields (which includes $\mathbb{R}$ but not $\mathbb{C}$), we are **guaranteed** to lose the ability to solve the equation $x^2+1=0$.
- When we shift from the class of *all* rings (which includes both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$) to the class of *discrete* rings (which includes $\mathbb{Z}$ but not $\mathbb{Q}$), we are **guaranteed** to lose the ability to solve the equation $2x=1$.

More restrictions make things more decisive, but even very "nice" restrictions do not necessarily make things *better*.

Comment: I am not entirely convinced. If you shift from the theory of *all* rings to the the class with the *zero* ring, you get ... well, a trivial object. I would not say this has "more guaranteed properties". Then again, the underlying issue is that "not having property $P$" can be restated as "having property $\neg P$", and in that sense all objects have equally many properties. -- We are actually looking for "interesting" properties, but a kingdom for the person who can make that notion rigorous ...

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg "I am not entirely convinced." I think you're misunderstanding me. It's trivially true that smaller classes of structures have more guaranteed properties: if $\mathcal{K}_0\subseteq\mathcal{K}_1$ and every structure in $\mathcal{K}_1$ has property $P$, then every structure in $\mathcal{K}_0$ has property $P$. My emphasis is on the word "**guaranteed**" here - given a class of structures $\mathcal{K}$, what properties do **all** structures in $\mathcal{K}$ have?

Comment: But part of my issue is that when you try to formalize that, does it not become a trivial statement, because bigger classes of structures also have more guaranteed properties (For every property $Q$ which all structures in $\mathcal{K}_0$ are "guaranteed" to have, let $\hat Q$ be the property "having or not having property $Q$" and say "every structure in $\mathcal{K}_1$ is guaranteed to have the property $\hat Q$") -- and hence, together with your statement, as I said: All classes of structures have equally many properties. Unless you have a cool definition of "property" which excludes this.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg No, that's false. The property $\hat{Q}=$ "Having or not having the property $Q$" is had by every structure in $\mathcal{K}_0$ as well as every structure in $\mathcal{K}_1$. There is no property which is had by every structure in $\mathcal{K}_1$ but not by every structure in $\mathcal{K}_0$; by contrast, if $\mathcal{K}_0\subsetneq\mathcal{K}_1$ then there is at least one property which every structure in $\mathcal{K}_0$ has which at least one structure in $\mathcal{K}_1$ doesn't, namely the property of not being in $\mathcal{K}_1\setminus\mathcal{K}_0$. There's no vacuity.

Comment: We can formalize properties perfectly well in, say, $\mathsf{NBG}$. The "loosest" way is the following: a property of structures is simply a class of structures closed under isomorphism, and a class of structures $\mathcal{K}$ has a property $P$ iff $\mathcal{K}\subseteq P$. Via logical considerations we can improve this: e.g. we can look at **first-order-expressible** properties, that is, properties of the form "The class of structures satisfying $\varphi$" for some first-order sentence $\varphi$. Here it is no longer the case that strictly smaller classes *always* satisfy more propreties ...

Comment: but on the other hand, we do get a much more interesting theory. But the overall point is that there's no difficulty in formalizing and proving the claim in question (although the result is a bit silly unless we add further restrictions, in which case the claim must be weakened).

Comment: OK, you got me there. But with $\mathcal{K}_0 = \{ \text{zero ring} \}$, so this class has extremely many "guaranteed" properties, each object in there is "guaranteed" to have ... every property of finite rings, artinian rings, noetherian rings, commutative rings, sure ... but also to *not* have more than 612 solutions to (whatever polynomial), to *not* have seven distinct ideals, to *not* have strictly less units than primes etc. And by the way, the same holds true for $\mathcal{K}_0 = \{ \mathbb F_{17}[x]/x^2 \}$. Are these interesting though? Maybe that is what you mean by a "a bit silly"?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Whether or not they're interesting, they're properties - indeed, first-order properties. As a logician I'd say that every first-order property is at least a little interesting - or, perhaps more accurately, paying attention to the overall behavior of first-order properties is interesting. (And I'd go well beyond first-order here.) "Smaller class = more guaranteed properties," while perhaps not earth-shattering, is in my opinion a deceptively important perspective shifter.

Comment: As to the "bit silly," that referred to the trivial proof of the statement if we interpret "property" as "arbitrary isomorphism-closed class of structures." It's not the properties which are a bit silly, it's the naive result. But the fact that the set of guaranteed first-order properties of $\{$zero ring$\}$ is a strict superset of the set of guaranteed first-order properties of $\{$all rings$\}$ is not silly at all, even if it is boringly obvious. For one thing, note that **not** every single structure is characterizable up to isomorphism by a first-order property - no infinite structure is!

Comment: Thinking about how a singleton (up to isomorphism) class of structures should be "maximal" with respect to the properties it guarantees (excluding the empty class of structures for obvious reasons), we're led to a very serious question indeed: what sorts of logics do we need to pin down various structures up to isomorphism? For example, by the compactness theorem no infinite structure is ever pin-downable by a first-order sentence, or even a first-order theory. However, every countable structure is pinned down by a $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence - which is nontrivial *and* important!

Comment: And that's just the tip of the iceberg. There's a whole vista of results opening up merely from the idea that singleton classes of structures are "property-guaranteeingly maximal," even though that seems very silly at first.

Comment: Well, I learned something today. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The "paradox" of Achilles and the Tortoise has nothing to do with uncountable infinities. It can be easily be phrased within the (countable) rationals, since it is about
$$\tag1
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}=1. 
$$
And in fact it doesn't require  infinity to be phrased, as it could be written as
$$\tag2
\forall \varepsilon>0,\ \exists N\in\mathbb N:\ \ \ \ 1-\varepsilon<\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{2^n}<1
$$
and proven within the field of rational numbers.
That said, the only paradox in the "paradox" lies in the mistake of not noticing that in the setup of the paradox time is also subject to $(2)$.

As for your example with the complex numbers, I fail where you want to go, but that kind of thinking can be made in scores of situations:

- In going from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb Q$ you "gain" that now every number is a fraction.
- In going from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Z$ you "gain" that every element has a predecessor and a successor.
- In going from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb N$ we "gain" that every subset has a first element.

It is easy to argue that there lots of "gains" going the other way, too.

Comment: The point with the complex numbers example in the OP is that $\mathbb{C}$ is not an [orderable field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) but $\mathbb{R}$ is.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: the "paradox", the way I know it, says nothing about Achilles getting arbitrarily close to the tortoise. But yes, one can add that condition.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: sorry, I don't see where you are going with that.

Comment: @MartinArgerami You wrote "As for your example with the complex numbers, I fail [to see?] where you want to go." Where the OP wants to go is the gain of orderability when we restrict to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Noah: yes, that I understand. My question was geared towards what is so particular about that example, as I provided other examples of "gains" (and there are lots of arguments for "gains" the other way around).

Comment: Martin, thanks for adding. If I were to nitpick, I'd say that even that formulation it still requires a certain infinite set, namely, the natural numbers, but let's leave it there ...

Answer (score 1):

First, regarding your first point, I agree with comments and answers pointing out that the Paradox of Achilles and the Tortoise has virtually nothing to do with uncountable infinities.

Regarding your second point, I would like to add something which I think is not stressed enough in other answers: Namely that **inclusion of structures $A \subset B$ says virtually nothing about how "complicated" or "interesting" the structures $A$ and $B$ are relative to each other**. That is because one could be interested in different structural properties of them.

As a graphical example, the Menger sponge (approximation on the right) is contained in the cube (on the left):

[image]

(Image from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge#/media/File:Menger_sponge_(Level_0-3).jpg)

Now which of these objects do you find more interesting, which has "more" or "less" properties? It very much depends on what you want. With the cube, you can compute a volume, study its symmetry group, do many non-trivial things ... But still the sponge on the right seems to have other, and more intricate, properties.

I like to compare that with the inclusion $\mathbb R\supset \mathbb Z$ (the real numbers being a bit like the cube).

- If you have, say, a series $\sum a_n$ with the $a_n \in \mathbb R$, there's quite an intricate theory about whether it absolutely converges or conditionally converges or does not converge at all etc.
- But if that series has terms $a_n$ taken just from $\mathbb Z$, this is absolutely boring: It converges if and anly if all but finitely many $a_n$ are $=0$, and then it'S just a finite sum.

So in that sense (namely, calculus / topology), the structure $\mathbb R$ is far more interesting than $\mathbb Z$.

But:

- For $n \ge 3$, does the equation $x^{n} + y^{n} =z^{n}$ have solutions with all $x,y,z \neq 0$ in $\mathbb R$? Well, trivially yes, infinitely many, you can graph them nicely and compute them to great accuracy with a pocket calculator.
- Does the equation $x^{n} + y^{n} =z^{n}$ have solutions with all $x,y,z \neq 0$ in $\mathbb Z$? No. But it took mathematicians hundreds of years and very intricate theories [to figure that out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem).

So in that sense (namely, solving equations / arithmetic), the structure $\mathbb Z$ is much more interesting than $\mathbb R$.